# onShouldVirtualize={() => true} is not supporting when we scroll down for more records of DetailsList

Tags: reactjs

Whenever we are givng onShouldVirtualize={() => false then functionality is working fine but performance is very slow. When we give onShouldVirtualize={() => true performance is improved but it is not loading more than 70 records when we scroll down the DetailList. Expectation: When we give onShouldVirtualize={() => true then it should load all records when we scroll down the DetailsList. Seems like issue is with dynamic height of react.

I have tried by giving DetailsList inside ScrollablePane and some approaches we have tried available in some git hubs eg-https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/8826 .
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/4601 But still no improvement

```
  <div className={Constants.ClassNames.List}>
      {this.editableGridConfiguration && (
          <DetailsList
              componentRef={this._root}
              items={items}
              groups={groups}
              columns={this.columns}
              setKey="set"
              selection={this.selection}
              selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
              selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
              ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
              ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
              checkButtonAriaLabel="select item"
              checkButtonGroupAriaLabel="select group"
              onShouldVirtualize={() => false}
              // onRenderDetailsHeader={this._onRenderDetailsHeader}
              onRenderRow={this._onRenderRow}
              // onRenderItemColumn={this._onRenderItemColumn}
              groupProps={{
                  showEmptyGroups: true,
                  onRenderHeader: this._onRenderGroupHeader,
              }}
              dragDropEvents={this._dragDropEvents}
              compact={false}
              styles={gridStyles}
          />
      )}
  </div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).